# How do I sniff wss (websocket) traffic that is handled in a swf?

Tags: websocket, packet-sniffers

I've tried Wireshark and that doesn't show any of the wss traffic, nor do Chrome developer tools and Firefox firebug. I know for sure websocket traffic is occurring. So, how do I monitor the traffic that is occurring on my computer?

Comment: If the websocket traffic is occurring in your web browser, you should see in the dev tools "Network" tab. Is it not showing there?

Comment: @JoshBeam no it does not

Answer (score 10):

Run this script in Chrome's console

You can modify and send the frames to a server via ajax

```js
(function() {
    WebSocket.prototype._send = WebSocket.prototype.send;
    WebSocket.prototype.send = function(data) {
        this._send(data);
        this.addEventListener('message', function(msg) {
            console.log('>> ' + msg.data);
        }, false);
        this.send = function(data) {
            this._send(data);
            console.log("<< " + data);
        };
    }
})();
```

Comment: The "elite" of stackoverflow are rejecting my edit although they apparently can't comprehend the nesting here. But for others who are trying to use this code, I suggest moving `console.log("<< " + data);` up one line, above the closing `};`. 

You can find the original and correct code on slide 52 of this PowerPoint:
http://www.hakim.ws/BHUSA12/materials/Briefings/Shekyan/BH_US_12_Shekyan_Toukharian_Hacking_Websocket_Slides.pdf

Hope this will help someone else, like it helped me.